# Laptop Overheating Issue - What should I replace?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, fan, cooling, overheating

So I have the Asus M50Vn (which is similar to the M50Sv, which there is a disassemble guide out there on Google if you'd like to know what mine looks like inside) that is about 6 years old and is having some over heating issues.

I'm including a couple of screen shots of temps so you can see the temps/fan speed while it is at idle. If I'm gaming, then the video card shoots up to over 105 degrees Celsius. 
[image: Idle 1]
[image: Idle 2]

Now I've clean out the dust out of this pretty well, so I'm not sure if it's the video card that is giving away or if I need a new fan. Anyone know?

Comment: Have you tried to adjust the quality of the graphics within these games?  Your computer is 6 years old.  The only think you might be able to do is reapply the thermal paste on the CPU heatsink.  Have you considered a laptop cooling pad?  Even if the problem is the GPU it can't be replaced since its a laptop.

Comment: @Ramhound: Admittedly, the video card is often the component that requires the most disassembly to reach and individual mobile cards are hard to come by, but replacement is not impossible just because it's installed in a laptop.

Comment: "some over heating issues" Care to elaborate on this?

Comment: @MarcksThomas - While you are indeed correct that there are laptops with graphic cards that can be removed. The GPU on this laptop is a mobile part soldered onto the motherboard. This part cannot be replaced ( at least without some very expesive hardware ). Also please note the term I used was `GPU` which isn't the samething has a `graphics card` huge difference.

Comment: What I'm thinking of doing is something similar to this: [link]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FRe4RlRf8w4&list=FL_81vNV7ZMJvRWdhJbbrfyA&index=1 [/link]       So, though I wont' replace the fan, to clean it out really well, and to remove all the old thermal paste and put on some new arctic silver.  I'm HOPING this helps.  

Also, the over heating issues is just that the computer gets way too hot, and since this is a side exhaust, I'll still get a cooling pad and just take off the back panel, and see if that helps too.

Comment: hope [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Apply-Thermal-Paste) help also